# Grouping values in dataframe by timerange Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tried solving this on my own and I just can't figure this one out. I have a number of transactions which are made up of more transactions. I am trying to group them together by 10 second intervals.

This is where I'm at. I've laid what I believe is the foundation but the most recent attempt ( the very last line ) comes back with "AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'to_period'".

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

"""
read csv file
clean date column
convert date str to datetime
sort for equity options
replace date str column with datetime column
"""
trade_reader = pd.read_csv('TastyTrades.csv')
trade_reader['Date'] = trade_reader['Date'].replace({'T': ' ', '-0500': ''}, regex=True)
date_converter = pd.to_datetime(trade_reader['Date'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
options_frame = trade_reader.loc[(trade_reader['Instrument Type'] == 'Equity Option')]
clean_frame = options_frame.replace(to_replace=['Date'], value='date_converter')

# Separate opening transaction from closing transactions, combine frames
opens = clean_frame[clean_frame['Action'].isin(['BUY_TO_OPEN', 'SELL_TO_OPEN'])]
closes = clean_frame[clean_frame['Action'].isin(['BUY_TO_CLOSE', 'SELL_TO_CLOSE'])]
open_close_set = set(opens['Symbol']) & set(closes['Symbol'])
open_close_frame = clean_frame[clean_frame['Symbol'].isin(open_close_set)]

# convert Value to float, sort, write
ocf_float = open_close_frame['Value'].astype(float)
ocf_sorted = open_close_frame.sort_values(by=['Symbol', 'Call or Put', 'Date'], ascending=True)
ocf_sorted.to_csv('Sorted.csv')

BTO_frame = opens[opens['Action'].isin(['BUY_TO_OPEN'])]
STO_frame = opens[opens['Action'].isin(['SELL_TO_OPEN'])]
debit_single = []
vertical = []
iron_condor = []
delta = timedelta(seconds=10)

temp_list = BTO_frame.groupby(BTO_frame['Date'].index.to_period(second=10))
```

A sample of what I am working with:

```
361,2020-01-15 15:27:18,Trade,BUY_TO_OPEN,QQQ   200221P00218000,Equity Option,Bought 1 QQQ 02/21/20 Put 218.00 @ 3.44,-344.00,1.0,-344.00,-1.0,-0.14,100.0,QQQ,2/21/20,218.0,PUT
356,2020-01-17 10:10:27,Trade,SELL_TO_CLOSE,QQQ   200221P00218000,Equity Option,Sold 1 QQQ 02/21/20 Put 218.00 @ 2.26,226.00,1.0,226.00,0.0,-0.15,100.0,QQQ,2/21/20,218.0,PUT
360,2020-01-15 15:27:18,Trade,SELL_TO_OPEN,QQQ   200221P00219000,Equity Option,Sold 1 QQQ 02/21/20 Put 219.00 @ 3.77,377.00,1.0,377.00,-1.0,-0.15,100.0,QQQ,2/21/20,219.0,PUT
357,2020-01-17 10:10:27,Trade,BUY_TO_CLOSE,QQQ   200221P00219000,Equity Option,Bought 1 QQQ 02/21/20 Put 219.00 @ 2.49,-249.00,1.0,-249.00,0.0,-0.14,100.0,QQQ,2/21/20,219.0,PUT
347,2020-01-24 12:28:19,Trade,BUY_TO_OPEN,QQQ   200221P00223000,Equity Option,Bought 1 QQQ 02/21/20 Put 223.00 @ 3.95,-395.00,1.0,-395.00,-1.0,-0.14,100.0,QQQ,2/21/20,223.0,PUT
299,2020-01-30 16:02:56,Trade,SELL_TO_CLOSE,QQQ   200221P00223000,Equity Option,Sold 1 QQQ 02/21/20 Put 223.00 @ 2.91,291.00,1.0,291.00,0.0,-0.15,100.0,QQQ,2/21/20,223.0,PUT
346,2020-01-24 12:28:19,Trade,SELL_TO_OPEN,QQQ   200221P00224000,Equity Option,Sold 1 QQQ 02/21/20 Put 224.00 @ 4.34,434.00,1.0,434.00,-1.0,-0.15,100.0,QQQ,2/21/20,224.0,PUT
300,2020-01-30 16:02:55,Trade,BUY_TO_CLOSE,QQQ   200221P00224000,Equity Option,Bought 1 QQQ 02/21/20 Put 224.00 @ 3.26,-326.00,1.0,-326.00,0.0,-0.14,100.0,QQQ,2/21/20,224.0,PUT
339,2020-01-27 09:56:51,Trade,SELL_TO_OPEN,QQQ   200320C00219000,Equity Option,Sold 1 QQQ 03/20/20 Call 219.00 @ 6.24,624.00,1.0,624.00,-1.0,-0.16,100.0,QQQ,3/20/20,219.0,CALL
15,2020-02-27 15:59:01,Trade,BUY_TO_CLOSE,QQQ   200320C00219000,Equity Option,Bought 1 QQQ 03/20/20 Call 219.00 @ 2.31,-231.00,1.0,-231.00,0.0,-0.14,100.0,QQQ,3/20/20,219.0,CALL
340,2020-01-27 09:56:51,Trade,BUY_TO_OPEN,QQQ   200320C00220000,Equity Option,Bought 1 QQQ 03/20/20 Call 220.00 @ 5.66,-566.00,1.0,-566.00,-1.0,-0.14,100.0,QQQ,3/20/20,220.0,CALL
14,2020-02-27 15:59:01,Trade,SELL_TO_CLOSE,QQQ   200320C00220000,Equity Option,Sold 1 QQQ 03/20/20 Call 220.00 @ 2.01,201.00,1.0,201.00,0.0,-0.15,100.0,QQQ,3/20/20,220.0,CALL
```

The end result would put these 12 transactions as 3 trades, grouped together by a 10 second time range when a date is found from the opening side per underlying symbol.

Edit:

A sample of the raw dataset:

```
Date,Type,Action,Symbol,Instrument Type,Description,Value,Quantity,Average Price,Commissions,Fees,Multiplier,Underlying Symbol,Expiration Date,Strike Price,Call or Put
2020-02-29T10:09:05-0500,Money Movement,,,,Regulatory fee adjustment,-0.28,0.0,,,0.00,,,,,
2020-02-28T16:00:00-0500,Receive Deliver,,M     200228C00019500,Equity Option,Removal of 3 M 02/28/20 Call 19.50 due to expiration.,0.00,3.0,0.00,,0.00,100,M,2/28/20,19.5,CALL
2020-02-28T15:36:34-0500,Trade,BUY_TO_OPEN,SVXY  200619C00085000,Equity Option,Bought 1 SVXY 06/19/20 Call 85.00 @ 0.06,-6.00,1.0,-6.00,-1.00,-0.14,100,SVXY,6/19/20,85.0,CALL
2020-02-28T15:33:32-0500,Trade,BUY_TO_OPEN,SVXY  200320C00069000,Equity Option,Bought 1 SVXY 03/20/20 Call 69.00 @ 0.15,-15.00,1.0,-15.00,-1.00,-0.14,100,SVXY,3/20/20,69.0,CALL
2020-02-28T12:06:13-0500,Trade,BUY_TO_OPEN,GME   200417C00010000,Equity Option,Bought 10 GME 04/17/20 Call 10.00 @ 0.01,-10.00,10.0,-1.00,-10.00,-1.39,100,GME,4/17/20,10.0,CALL
2020-02-28T12:05:54-0500,Trade,BUY_TO_OPEN,GME   200417C00004500,Equity Option,Bought 1 GME 04/17/20 Call 4.50 @ 0.23,-23.00,1.0,-23.00,-1.00,-0.14,100,GME,4/17/20,4.5,CALL
2020-02-28T10:23:57-0500,Trade,SELL_TO_OPEN,VXX   200417C00025000,Equity Option,Sold 1 VXX 04/17/20 Call 25.00 @ 3.39,339.00,1.0,339.00,-1.00,-0.15,100,VXX,4/17/20,25.0,CALL
2020-02-28T10:23:57-0500,Trade,BUY_TO_OPEN,VXX   200417C00026000,Equity Option,Bought 1 VXX 04/17/20 Call 26.00 @ 3.02,-302.00,1.0,-302.00,-1.00,-0.14,100,VXX,4/17/20,26.0,CALL
```

Comment: Could you please include a sample of the raw dataset complete with the column heads?

Comment: @wwnde Okay I put that in there.

Comment: Thanks, Could you elaborate on this statement 'The end result would put these 12 transactions as 3 trades, grouped together by a 10 second time range when a date is found from the opening side per underlying symbol.' You need trades grouped by? What is the opening side? I cant see that in your columns?

Comment: I need the BTO_frame Action column BUY_TO_OPEN and SELL_TO_OPEN sorted by Date, Underlying Symbol, and then finally counting the number of transactions per date within a 10 second range to push to a designated list based on that count.

The first sample I have provided should be evenly split into 3 trades made up of 2 opening transactions within a 10 second range for the same underlying symbol and that these are pushed to vertical.

Answer (score 0):

Please try and see if I understood you right. I have saved your data as csv and loaded the dataframe as `opens`.
The new dataframe has the following columns;

```
['Date', 'Type', 'Action', 'Symbol', 'Instrument Type', 'Description',
       'Value', 'Quantity', 'Average Price', 'Commissions', 'Fees',
       'Multiplier', 'Underlying Symbol', 'Expiration Date', 'Strike Price',
       'Call or Put']
```

**I convert Date column to a datetime**

```
 opens['Date']=pd.to_datetime(opens['Date'])
```

**I set the Date Column as the dataframe index**

```
opens.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

I group the dataframe by Action and Symbol, while categorizing the index in a 10 second interval.Simultaneously, I count the Types in each group within the the interval

```
opens.groupby(["Action","Symbol"]).resample("10S"). apply(lambda x: x['Type'].count())
```

Or did you want?

```
opens.groupby(["Action","Symbol"]).resample("10S"). apply(lambda x: x['Type'].count()).unstack()
```

What does pushing to vertical mean?From your code, vertical is a dictionary. What are its keys and what should be the values?

Comment: I get: "KeyError: 'Type'". I changed type to something else and it's still the same result. I also changed "symbol' to 'underlying symbol'. Push to vertical means that i'm simply appending each whole transaction to a list called vertical, in the original code i've provided, as a single variable/object whatever it is.

Comment: I also don't know what 'type' is. Maybe you were referring to 'instrument type'?

Comment: Okay, so using the following code: `opens['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(opens['Date'])
opens.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
opens.groupby(["Action", "Underlying Symbol"]).resample("10S")`
I get the following result:
`SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  opens['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(opens['Date'])`

Comment: From your code, vertical = {} is a dictionary. What will be the keys and what do you want the values to be?

Comment: I didn't realize sets were deprecated. I am going to change it to `[]` now.

Comment: I'm getting errors no matter what I do. Huge, huge, huge blocks of error.